# StorageClass ProvisioningFailed: unsupported key found in matchLabelExpressions: topology.kubernetes.io/region

Tags: kubernetes, storage

I have setup VMware vSphere Cloud Provider in Kubernetes (Rancher). I'm using Kubernetes' in-tree vSphere cloud provider.

I want to use vSphere storage provider to provision and attach a VMDK to the nodes (the virtual machines).

I get the following error

```
Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "test-sc": unsupported key found in matchLabelExpressions: topology.kubernetes.io/region
```

The Storageclass YAML file is:

```yaml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
allowVolumeExpansion: false
metadata:
  name: test-sc
parameters:
  datastore: TESTDATASTORE
  diskformat: zeroedthick
  fstype: ext4
provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
reclaimPolicy: Delete
#volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
allowedTopologies:
  - matchLabelExpressions:
#    - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region
   - key: topology.kubernetes.io/region
      values: [region-a]
#    - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
      values: [zone-a]
```

I have a similar error when I use `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region` :

```
Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "test-sc": unsupported key found in matchLabelExpressions: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region
```

The PVC YAML file is:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: test
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: test-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

Running Kubectl describe...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/creatorId: u-azgclvtap4
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
  creationTimestamp: "2020-10-08T13:01:07Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    cattle.io/creator: norman
  name: test
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "24011763"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/test
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: test-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Pending
> kubectl describe  pvc/test        
Name:          test
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  test-sc
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        cattle.io/creator=norman
Annotations:   field.cattle.io/creatorId: u-azgclvtap4
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                  From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                 ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  37s (x7 over 2m15s)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "test-sc": unsupported key found in matchLabelExpressions: topology.kubernetes.io/region
```

Answer (score 1):

The current upstream documentation of the *Allowed Topologies*, doesn't indicate that `region`is  supported.

> When a cluster operator specifies the WaitForFirstConsumer volume binding mode, it is no longer necessary to restrict provisioning to specific topologies in most situations. However, if still required, allowedTopologies can be specified.
>
> This example demonstrates how to restrict the topology of provisioned volumes to specific zones and should be used as a replacement for the zone and zones parameters for the supported plugins.
>
> (abstract from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#allowed-topologies )

The source code for [zones](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/323f34858de18b862d43c40b2cced65ad8e24052/staging/src/k8s.io/cloud-provider/volume/helpers/zones.go) support in Kubernetes doesn't seems to have an equivalent for regions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be given as a zone, the region is not supported

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: region1storageclass
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  encrypted: "true" # if encryption required, kms keys need to be created
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - eu-east-2b
```